# Question About The Generation of The Borel $\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, borel-sets

I am new to measure theory. I was asked to prove the following result:

> **Proposition**$\quad$ *The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is generated by each of the following collections of sets:*
>
> 1. *the collection of all closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$;*
> 2. *the collection of all closed half-spaces in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that have the form $\{(x_1,\dots,x_d):x_i \leq b\}$ for some index $i$ and some $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$;*
> 3. *the collection of all rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that have the form*
>    \begin{align*}
>        \{(x_1,\dots,x_d):a_i < x_i \leq b_i\ \textit{for}\ i = 1,\dots,d \}.    
>    \end{align*}

where

> **Definition**$\quad$ The smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that includes $\mathcal{F}$ is called the $\sigma$-algebra *generated* by $\mathcal{F}$.
>
> **Definition**$\quad$ The *Borel $\sigma$-algebra* on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$ generated by the collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$; it is denoted by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. The *Borel subsets* of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are those that belong to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Here is my attempt:

> **Proof**$\quad$ Let $\mathcal{B}_1$, $\mathcal{B}_2$, and $\mathcal{B}_3$ be the $\sigma$-algebras generated by the collections of sets in parts (1), (2), and (3) of the proposition. We will show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d) \supseteq \mathcal{B}_1 \supseteq \mathcal{B}_2 \supseteq \mathcal{B}_3$ and then that $\mathcal{B}_3 \supseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$; this will establish the proposition.
>
> Since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ includes the family of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and is closed under complementation, it includes the family of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$; thus it includes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, namely $\mathcal{B}_1$.
>
> The sets of the form $\{(x_1,\dots,x_d):x_i \leq b\}$ for some index $i$ and some $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and so belong to $\mathcal{B}_1$; consequently $\mathcal{B}_1 \supseteq \mathcal{B}_2$.
>
> Note that each strip that has the form $\{(x_1,\dots,x_d):a < x_i \leq b\}$ for some $i$ is the difference of two of the half-spaces in part (2) and that each of the rectangles in part (3) is the intersection of $d$ such strips. So, each rectangles in part (3) belongs to $\mathcal{B}_2$; thus $\mathcal{B}_2 \supseteq \mathcal{B}_3$.
>
> Finally, note that each strip that has the form $\{(x_1,\dots,x_d):a < x_i < b\}$ for some $i$ is the union of a sequence of sets of the form $\{(x_1,\dots,x_d):p < x_i \leq q\}$ for the same $i$, that each open rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the intersection of $d$ such strips, and that each open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the union of a sequence of open rectangles. Thus, each open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ belongs to $\mathcal{B}_3$, and so $\mathcal{B}_3 \supseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Could someone please help me check if my proof is correct and rigorous? Thanks a lot in advance!